# Silverlight 4 DataGrid edit null value's cell

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I'm creating a DataGrid where I set ItemsSource of the grid to a WCF request result. I have some null values for some strings, and I want to be able to enter values for those null values. I have no problems editing/saving pre-populated non-null values, but I can't modify the values of cells which have been returned as null. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Converter in your Binding that converts the null value to an empty string. Here is some code for the converter:

```
public class NullToEmptyStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? string.Empty : value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == string.Empty ? null : value;
    }
}
```

Comment: i get all the non-null values called into the converter, but null values just won't go into the converter. i've got breakpoints in convert and convertback methods, but they won't fire for null values so it gets no use.

Comment: i've got the wcf call returning items, and settings ItemsSource of my grid on the completed event. the grid displays them correctly (i have custom columns such as `<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource NullStringConverter}}" Header="Title"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>` if that changes anything), where NullStringConverter is an instance of the value converter defined as a static resource key in App.xaml. The conventer will fire for non null values, but won't fire for nulls, rendering the converter useless.

Comment: What is the structure of the ItemsSource? (the WCF service request) It seems like I am missing a crutial part of the problem because I have never seen a converter which hits for some bindings and not for others.

Comment: it's a `List` of `Category` defined as `List<Category> categories;` and (when the wcf call completes `categories= e.Result` and right after in another method `CategoryGrid.ItemsSource = categories;` and I verify that the list returns correct data and when I set the ItemsSource I get the grid displayed correctly and I can edit/save too with `RowEditEnded` event. But the problem is null values.

Comment: If you review the data during debugging prior to setting the itemssource, does the categories do indeed have a null value for Title or is it something else?

Comment: oh, i can't believe i'm THIS stupid, i had a typo in the column data bindings in XAML which wasn't throwing up any errors, and those fields were simply empty and wasn't showing up. why i couldn't realize easily is that some of the valid columns also had some values i knew were actually null, but i (not thinking that i'd had a typo in particular columns but not others) was clicking in the typo-ed columns and as they were read only, thought there was a general problem since some fields just displayed the values well.. my bad, and it was why value converter wasn't firing either obviously..

Comment: It's no problem. I've spent time on much more trivial things before only to kick myself later. Glad it works now. :)